# Is specifying column_metadata when declaring a cassandra family always a good idea?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I know that column_metadata can be used to provide configuration for any column but more often than not, I don't have a need for column-specific configurations.  When that's the case, is there any advantage in using column_metadata when I create my family?

Specifically, is there any advantage in writing:

```
create column family session
    with comparator = UTF8Type
    and column_metadata =
    [{
        column_name : account,
        validation_class : UTF8Type
    }
];
```

instead of

```
create column family session
    with comparator = UTF8Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a question on Comparators or Validation_class ? The two AFAIK have two very different meanings.

In your example above, the way I read it is

1) Your Column_names are going to be UTF8Type strings.
2) You have not defined any default_validation_class and hence every column_value is validated using bytes type (i.e no validation)
3) You want the column "account" to have values of the the type UTF8. If you were going to store Account numbers with no Alphabets in them, you could specify a Long something like this.

```
**create column family session
    with comparator = UTF8Type
    and column_metadata =
    [{
        column_name : account,
        validation_class : Long
    }
];**
```

After this, in your account column you can only store numbers.

To cut the story short, Comparator is the datatype of Column_Name. Validation_class is for value of column and can be different for different columns.
Hope this helps.